# Touchpad recognised as a generic mouse

Tags: touchpad, 20.04, lenovo, synaptics, elantech

I've just re-installed 20.04 (dual boot with Windows 10) on my Lenovo ideapadY700. My laptop recognises touchpad as mouse. I have no other mouse plugged.

I'm new in Ubuntu and I don't know much...

```
$ uname -a
Linux nando-Lenovo 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ dmesg | grep psmouse
[   30.218871] psmouse serio1: elantech: synaptics_send_cmd query 0x01 failed.
[   30.218879] psmouse serio1: elantech: failed to query firmware version.
[  165.209816] psmouse serio1: Wheel Mouse at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.
[  216.923481] psmouse serio1: Wheel Mouse at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.
[  468.662298] psmouse serio1: Wheel Mouse at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.
[  553.556484] psmouse serio1: Wheel Mouse at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 2 bytes away.
```

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0001 Version=0063
N: Name="PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input19
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event16 
B: PROP=1
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
```

I have read a lot of solutions; I tried to use xorg, but it didn't work.

When I removed it, it worked for a day (only) and I decided erase and re-install Ubuntu.

Comment: I told you already that this the mouse, that is detected as a mouse.

Comment: I removed the mouse and didn't plugged it in since

Comment: And it still shows Logitech mouse?

Comment: Yes... it is really frustrating

Comment: That must be a kernel bug. Report it to launchpad by `ubuntu-bug linux` command.

Comment: I will... any other additional command for the bug report? Thanks Pilot6

Comment: The command will do all you. You will need to explain th symptoms. It will run and send all necessary debug comands.

Comment: Done
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1882388
Is it ok to work with a traditional mouse then?
Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

I have realised that if I restart the mouse *twice in a row*, the touchpad is recognised as such and starts working for a period of time.

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Then, it is recognised back as a generic mouse and stops working.

It is a temporary fix, as I have to restart the mouse constantly...

I have also logged a bug on launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1882388

Comment: I can suggest to add this information to the bug report. Bugs can't be fixed here, and they are off-topic.

Comment: I did, as a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. It looks like blacklisting the psmouse module fixed it and it doesn't even stop a traditional mouse from working when plugged in.

Not sure if that works for you as well (I have a Dell with single boot Arch), but if you still have the issue it might be worth a try.